# top bar not visible after programmatically pushing UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In the AppDelegate i check if there is a user existing, if there is i "skip" two ViewControllers by pushing a NavigationController using this code:

```
if(currentUser){

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Test"];

    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    viewController.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO; // Tried this nothing happened.
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
else{
    [PFUser enableAutomaticUser];
    [[PFUser currentUser] incrementKey:@"RunCount"];
    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
    [[PFUser currentUser] fetch];


    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstView"];

    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

So the true statement skips two ViewControllers and push the UINavigationController. But when it shows it this way there is no top bar.

However if there was no user then it would proceed to the UINavigationController in a "normal" way by segues then the bar is visible.

How can i fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
 bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard 
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Test"];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

Answer (score 0):

"So the true statement skips two ViewControllers and push the UINavigationController." No, it doesn't. First of all you're not pushing anything, you're setting the window's root view controller. Secondly, you haven't created any navigation controller, you've only created viewController.

If viewController has a navigation controller in the storyboard, then you should instantiate the navigation controller (which will, in turn, instantiate viewController), and make it the window's root view controller.

Comment: I guess ur saying what the William Hu is saying so ill accept his answer since he provides code to make it easier for other ppl. Thank you for making it clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set a UINavigationController to rootviewController , there will be a navigation bar. So you can also set the firstView as rootViewController, but set the viewcontrollers attribute to put the Test viewcontroller that clears before viewcontrollers.